# indicator-cpufreq in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, desktop, power-management, cpu-frequency

I'm an Ubuntu user testing out Arch Linux. So far I'm happy.

On Ubuntu I used the indicator-cpufreq applet to control power profile both on Unity and Gnome-shell.

On Arch, I cannot figure out how this can be done. How can I have a simple way to choose which power profile I wish to use?

Comment: have you taken a look here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling ?

Comment: Yes. There's no direct equivalent to the applet in Ubuntu. Furthermore the gnome extensions site says that the applet is outdated.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/indicator-powersave/

Comment: Tried installing it but couldn't install `libappindicator` that is a dependency.